# Creating scikit learn objects

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Want to creat objects like:

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
```

with:

```
GaussianNB()
SVC() 
svm.SVR()
DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

For example, for:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
gaussian = naive_bayes.GaussianNB()
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'naive_bayes' is not defined
```

For:

```
from  sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
treeclassifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'tree' is not defined
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just `gaussian = GaussianNB()` and `treeclassifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()` should work

Answer (score 2):

When you import an object *from* a submodule, you use the object directly: for example

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
model = GaussianNB()
```

when you import *the submodule itself*, you can use that submodule name in your code. For example:

```
from sklearn import naive_bayes
model = naive_bayes.GaussianNB()
```

Make sure your import statements match your code!

Answer (score 0):

For each of those, there is an API-page, like [this one](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html). Every API-page at least provides one example (of basic usage)!

If you observed errors, it's probably due to import-style. I can't find some doc-page for that at the moment, but the basic examples are all you need.

So it's just:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()

from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()

from sklearn.svm import SVR
clf = SVR()

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
```

Comment: Then observe the difference between your usage and mine shown. The more complete answer is given by [jake](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850271/2320035).